# Bug in Array.prototype.includes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, v8

I encountered strange behavior of `Array.prototype.includes` in one edge case.

Given that `Array.prototype.includes` works on bound context, one might use it like this (which is working)

```
expect(Array.prototype.includes.call([1, 2], 1))).toBe(true)
```

simply put, we bound array `[1, 2]` and test `1` for inclusion.

Then consider, that many Array.prototype methods are able to bound context to provided callback, so for example `Array.prototype.some` can be combined with `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` like this

```
expect(["foo", "bar"].some(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, { foo: 0 })).toBe(true)
```

Here, `.some` accepts two parameters, `(callback, [thisArg])`, where optional `thisArg`, when provided, is bound to callback, thus previous example binds `{ foo: 0 }` to callback `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` and then tests all items in `["foo", "bar"]` if at least one is own property of `{ foo: 0 }`. This example is also working.

But something strange happen, if you try to use `Array.prototype.includes` as callback.

```
[0, 1].some(Array.prototype.includes, [1]) // => false
```

here we bind array `[1]` to `Array.prototype.includes` and we test every item of `[0, 1]` if at least one is included. But this case returns false, which is against our expectation.

Strangely, if bound array contains other number than `1` or contains more than one item, the test passes

```
[0, 1].some(Array.prototype.includes, [0]) // => true
[0, 1].some(Array.prototype.includes, [1, 1]) // => true
// but
[0, 1].some(Array.prototype.includes, [1]) // => false
```

It seems like array `[1]` is handled improperly.

Tested in
Node v.11.11.0
Node v.8.11.3
and Chrome 73

I tested basically just V8 engine. Can anyone report output in Chakra?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a bug in `includes`. :-)

The problem is that `includes` accepts an optional second parameter, which is the index at which to start searching, and `some` provides three arguments to its callback: The item, its index, and the object being searched.

So with

```
[0, 1].some(Array.prototype.includes, [1])
```

These calls are made (effectively):

- `[1].includes(0, 0)` - false, the array doesn't contain `0`
- `[1].includes(1, 1)` - false, the array contains `1` at index `0`, but the search starts at index `1`

This comes up periodically. For instance, when trying to use `parseInt` as a callback directly to convert an array of strings into an array of numbers, because of `parseInt`'s second parameter (the number base, or radix, to use):

```js
console.log(["6", "9", "7"].map(parseInt));
```

The `9` and `7` fail becaue the calls are (effectively):

- `parseInt("6", 0)` - works because `parseInt` ignores the invalid radix `0`.
- `parseInt("9", 1)` - `NaN` because `parseInt` always returns `NaN` for radix `1`
- `parseInt("7", 2)` - `NaN` because `"7"` is not a valid digit in base 2 (binary)

**The moral of the story**: Remember the not-commonly-used arguments that `map`, `some`, `forEach`, and various other methods provide to callbacks. :-)

---

In one codebase I was working in, they had a `clamp` function that accepted a function and ensured that, regardless of how many arguments it was called with, it would only pass on the desired number of arguments. If you were using `includes` like this a lot, you could create a clamped `includes`:

```js
function clamped(fn, count) {
    return function(...args) {
        return fn.apply(this, args.slice(0, count));
    }
}

const includes = clamped(Array.prototype.includes, 1);

console.log([0, 1].some(includes, [1])); // true
console.log([0, 1].some(includes, [3])); // false
```

The handy thing about that is that that `includes` is reusable.

Or of course, just use a wrapper function:

```js
console.log([0, 1].some(function(entry) {
    return this.includes(entry);
}, [1])); // true
console.log([0, 1].some(function(entry) {
    return this.includes(entry);
}, [3])); // false
```

---

These are all meant to be *general* solutions, of course. If you specifically want to know if array `a` contains any of the entries in array `b`, there are more specific implementations you can build to handle that efficiently depending on the characteristics of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm aware of this problem, but I did not knew that `includes` has arity of 2 and I did not suspect this be a problem. I will use Ramdas utility function [`unary`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unary) to handle this scenario. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Did you mean, "just use an **anonymous** function"?

Comment: @justDev7a3 - LOL I certainly didn't mean "arrow function." :-) Thanks!